# React Query doesn't fetch API - causing data to return 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript, react-query, json-server, tanstackreact-query

I've been trying to `GET` data from the JSON-server using `@tanstack/react-query` in the same code pattern that worked for me in [another project](https://github.com/iceyisaak/cineverse/blob/main/src/pages/movies-page/movies-page.tsx). However, this time the function seems to have not been called for some reason, causing the data to return 'undefined'. What am I missing here?

Here is the code in the component `task-list.tsx`:

```
import { fetchAllTasks } from "../../api/tasks-api"
import TaskItem from "./task-item/task-item"

import style from './task-list.module.scss'



const TaskList = () => {

    // This supposed to work, but isn't!
    const { data: tasks, isLoading } = fetchAllTasks()
    

    // This logs: undefined
    console.log('tasklists - fetchAllTasks:', tasks) 


    return (
        <div className={`${style['TaskList']}`}>
            <ul>
                {
                    !isLoading && tasks && tasks?.length < 1 ?
                        <p className={`${style['no-task']}`}>
                            +++ Task List is Empty +++
                        </p>
                        :
                        tasks?.map((task) =>
                            <TaskItem
                                key={task.toString()}
                                atom={task}
                            />
                        )
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TaskList
```

Here is the `fetchAllTasks()` function in `task-api.ts`:

```
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query"
import axios from "axios"
import { Task } from "../types"


export const fetchAllTasks = () => {

    return useQuery({
        queryKey: ['tasks'],
        queryFn: async () => {
            const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3100/tasks')
            const data: unknown = await response.data()
            
            // This doesn't appear in the console log at all
            console.log('data: ', data)


            return data as Task[]
        }
    })
}
```

Here is what shows up in the browser:

[image: The bug as shown in the browser]

Here is the response from the backend:

[image]

Here is how the network tab of the browser looks like after a page refresh.

[image]

[image]

The link to the project repo:
https://github.com/iceyisaak/todoapp/tree/tanstack-query/src

Help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: Have you verified that the request succeeds in the network tab of the browser? It could fail because of CORS issues or something else.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I have added the screenshots to provide more info regarding that. I'd really love to know your thoughts on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios returns data as property, so you do not invoke data as method on the response object and because it is a property you do not need to use await.

```
 const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3100/tasks')
 const data: unknown = response.data
```

Comment: That was the killer bug!! Thank you so much for your invaluable help!